# How to synchronize android Handlers with different intervals?

Tags: android, android-service, android-handler

I have two handlers running within an Android `Service`.

- `handler1` runs every 30 seconds
- `handler2` runs every 5 seconds

The problem is, `handler2` can't run at the same time as `handler1`.

I mean, when `handler2` reaches 30, 60, 90... secs it will run at the same time as `handler1`.

So, I need to find a way during those 30, 60 90 secs to run one handler after another.

I know a solution for this could be, but it's not elegant, neither accurate:

- Run `handler1` at second `0`
- Wait `7` seconds (or any other `x` # of secs no-multiple of 5)

Comment: Do you want handler2 to wait for handler1, or skip that iteration and fire again in 5 seconds?

Comment: Hey @dharms, I think both could work but waiting for `handler1` fits perfect for my use case.

Comment: Try using a `synchronized` block on a common object around the code for your Handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Since handler2 runs more frequently than handler1 does, you can use counter in handler2 to track when to fire the events that you plan to trigger in handler1.

```
handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (count == 0) {
            // fire handler1 events
        }
        count = (count+1) % 6;
    }
}, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [TimerTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask) and [Timer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer) to schedule repeated executions (every 5 seconds)? Depending on the interval, you run either the job currently done in `handler1`, or the one in `handler2`, or both. Perhaps you can break out these jobs into functions that are called from the `TimerTask's` run method. That would let the `handler1` job run before the `handler2` job, in a synchronized manner on the same thread.